# Por que o if não está comparando com entidade html &lt;?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span>&lt;</span>
    
    <script>
        let text = document.querySelector("span");
        
        text.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (text.textContent == "&lt;")
            {
                alert("é igual")
            }
            
            else
            {
                alert("não é igual")
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O exemplo acima estou tentando comparar se dois valores são iguais no caso `&lt;` é igual a `&lt;` no caso tinha que me retornar `true`, mas está me retornando `false`, por que?

Answer (score 7):

Basicamente pelo fato de você estar confundindo o conteúdo do elemento com a representação HTML.

O conteúdo textual (`textContent`) do `span` é `<` e não `&lt;` (é o que você usou no código), portanto a comparação correta é:

```
text.textContent == "<"
```

Se tivesse usado `innerHTML`, aí sim esta comparação funcionaria:

```
text.innerHTML == "&lt;"
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
var text = document.querySelector("span");
console.log( 'Texto é igual &lt;? : ' + (text.textContent == "&lt;") );
console.log( 'Texto é igual < ? : ' + (text.textContent == "<") );
console.log( 'HTML é igual &lt;? : ' + (text.innerHTML == "&lt;") );
console.log( 'HTML é igual < ? : ' + (text.innerHTML == "<") );
```

```html
<span>&lt;</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

A representação real desta linha

```
<span>&lt;</span>
```

é "<" e por isso deves fazer a comparação desta maneira:

```
text.textContent == "<"
```